# Giving up on css, cant make one simple button to be on the bot of the div

Tags: html, css, button, division

I have two divs, and i want one button to be on the bottom of the div. I tried everything that i see online. Nothing works!

html :

```
<ion-col >
          <div id="secondCol">
          <ion-text> {{card.cardPoints}} = {{card.cardValue}} € </ion-text>
<!--          <ion-text>{{userPercentageCards[i]}} %</ion-text>-->
            <div id="useButton">
              <ion-button  *ngIf="userPercentageCards[i] >=100" style="bottom: 0"> Usar Cartão!</ion-button>
            </div>

          </div>
        </ion-col>
```

css:

```
#secondCol{
 position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#useButton{
   position: relative;

  bottom: 0;
 }
```

I want the button to be at the bottom of the div, but it stays at the same place no matther what i change.

I am almost giving up on css, i hate this!

Comment: I feel your pain, I also hate CSS. But I usually just mess around with it in the developer tools on chrome and eventually I get to where I want to be. You should try something like bootstrap to make things easier. All the CSS is pre-made essentially and you just use their classes.

Comment: @LewisMorris He's already using a framework.

Comment: I didnt even look at it to be fair haha his problem was with CSS just like mine

Comment: @LewisMorris. No shame. ;D

Comment: @Simplicius None at all !! ;)

Answer (score 4):

Try this: ;)

```
#secondCol{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#useButton{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
 }
```

Comment: Lol...we were in a minute apart with identical CSS

Comment: @DanMullin Yeah, xD

Answer (score 2):

Make the parent element relative and the child absolute:

```
#secondCol {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#useButton {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```